# Issues with too many interactive plotly figures

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook on my laptop (the version coming with Anaconda) to perform some sensitivity analysis.
I use plotly to display the results and I like the interactive features that it has.
However, when I am trying to display more than 7/8 interactive plots on the same notebook, some plots disappears and the output cells of those plots go crazy (see picture attached).
[Issue with plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Yyu.png)

A solution I found was to disable the interactive feature at least for some of the plots, changing the diplay mode in config as:

```
config = {'staticPlot': True}
fig.show(config=config)
```

This method works, however, I like the feature and I was wondering if there was a solution that does not imply disabling the interactive view.

I read about this post where they say it might be a memory issue (even though their graphs are going blank while mine are behaving crazy):
[Plotly: How to prevent graphs from going blank when there are too many interactive plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63875365/plotly-how-to-prevent-graphs-from-going-blank-when-there-are-too-many-interacti)

However I did not manage to find/change the jupyter configuration file, maybe because I installed it via Anaconda?

I was also wondering if someone experienced exactly the same or there might be a simpler solution to this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in the second link the config file should be generated if not existing.

You can also try changing to gl rendering:

https://plotly.com/python/webgl-vs-svg/

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I am already using GL rendering (doing scatter plots with go.Scattergl) but it does not seem to affect my issue. I have also used it in the past for plotting graphs with large amounts of data points. In this case, the plots are quite simple with only few data points (max 500 or so). I will try again with the jupyter configuration file. You are right, it is created since it did not existed, but it is entirely commented out. Should I uncomment the line that interest me and try to change the max memory allocated maybe?

Comment: Just as an update: I did it. I updated the jupyter configuration file increasing the max buffer size but it is not solving my issue.